# Read file from terminal input "cat" on C

Tags: c, file, csv, cat

I'm making a program that read CSV files based on the arguments of the C program called read-log

example

```
$ ./read-log file1.csv

$ ./read-log file1.csv file2.csv nofile.csv
```

But I also need my program to read files when using the unix command `cat` but when I input:

```
$ cat file1.csv |./read-log
```

The program doesn't get any argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `FILE *stdin` that is open by default:

```
FILE *fp;

if (argc > 1) {
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-") == 0)     // Many utilities accept "-" for the
        fp = stdin;                    // filename to indicate stdin
    else
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
}
else {
    fp = stdin;
}
```

When you're done using the file, make sure you only close it if you actually opened it: (Closing `stdin` can lead to some *interesting* bugs down the road!)

```
if (fp != stdin)
    fclose(fp);
```

Comment: +1 but you may want to add at the end: `if (fp != stdin) fclose(fp);`, just for tidiness.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks, forgot about that. Probably did the same in the last thing I wrote that used this too :-P

Comment: In a POSIX compliant environment (*e.g.*, Linux, Windows), there's no harm in `fclose(stdin);` as long as there are no more attempts to read from `stdin` after the `fclose` in the program.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon, the problem now is that if I don't use the cat command it keeps waiting for an input, and i want it to show a default file I was trying something like 
fp=stdin;
if(fp == NULL) {
filename = strdup("something.csv"); 

But as I said the program keeps on waiting for an input

Comment: @user3460464 You're saying, with my code (or equivalent), and you just run `read-log` (with no inputs), the program just waits for input? That's exactly what should happen. Try running `cat` by itself.